# How to not operate on a directory if *.tmp exists anywhere in it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

This code should go though all top level directories in the current directory, executing a temp file check and if none exist it moves the directory.

```
$processDirectories = {
    foreach ($childDirectory in Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory) {
        test-path "$childDirectory\*.tmp"
        move-item -LiteralPath "$childDirectory" -Destination "d:\"
    }
}
```

I don't know how to stop running the code for directories where `*.tmp` is found. Plus this method only checks the root of each subdir for `*.tmp` and not the entire tree within.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. You want to move a directory when it (or subfolders of it) does **NOT** contain a `*.tmp` file? And why do you put your code in a script block?

Comment: You got it, when it does NOT contain `*.tmp`. And you're right, I guess I don't need the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your restrictions right here are two variants,
counting the number of `*.tmp` in the subfolders. If zero then Move-Item the folder.

1. Iterating the 1st level folders

   ```
   foreach ($childDirectory in Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory) {
     if ((Get-ChildItem $childDirectory -recurse -Include *.tmp, *.!qb).Count -eq 0){
       Move-Item -LiteralPath "$childDirectory" -Destination "d:\" -WhatIf
     }
   }
   ```
2. a single pipeline

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory | Where-Object {
     (Get-ChildItem $_ -recurse -Include *.tmp, *.!qb).Count -eq 0} |
       Move-Item -Destination "d:\" -WhatIf
   ```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

Comment: The first version works perfect (with `_WhatIf` fixed). The second version not at all. I get no output, no moving of valid dirs. Same with or without `-WhatIf`. How do I use the single pipeline version? I can read that one much easier.

Comment: 2nd variant had an erroneous closing parenthesis leftover, corrected. The 1st gci list the folders, the 2nd inside the where excludes the ones with any `*.tmp` file and pipes them on to the Move-Item

Comment: Works, thank you for the education! How would I check for another blacklisted extension too, say, `*.!qb`? It won't let me add them like `Get-ChildItem $_ -recurse "*.tmp","*.!qb"`

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks for the edit. (at)Bricktop as suggested use th `-Include  *.tmp, *.!qb` parameter

Comment: As an aside: With only _one_ pattern, `-Filter *.tmp` would be much faster than just `*.tmp` (implied `-Path` parameter); unfortunately, `-Filter` doesn't support _multiple_ patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `if`

```
 foreach ($childDirectory in Get-ChildItem -Force -Directory) {
     if (!(test-path "$childDirectory\*.tmp")) {
        move-item -LiteralPath "$childDirectory" -Destination "d:\"
     }
 }
```

Regarding subdirectories, use `-Recurse` switch of `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: This checks each directory within the top level directories individually and then moves them individually. I need top level directories checked and moved as a whole.

Comment: @Bricktop Not quite sure what do you mean by *moved as a whole*. An example, please?